# Tuples without self-loop

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a simple question coincerning the *Mathematica* function `Tuple`.

Currently, I apply the following code

```
x = {1, 2, 3};
Tuples[x, 2]
```

Obviously I get:

[image]

How can I delete all self-loops from this list, i.e., delete `{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}`? Is there a built-in function?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you want `Permutations`:

```
Permutations[{1, 2, 3}, {2}]
```

> {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 1}, {2, 3}, {3, 1}, {3, 2}}

Comment: perfect. Thanks a lot